# Google Model Viewer no reflections on object on Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to display a model of a water tap with a chrome finish/texture with the Google Model Viewer.

I currently have the problem that on Android in the AR View (not in the preview / 3D model view) I cannot see any reflections of the material (the finish looks like satin / matte). In the 3D Model View of the Model Viewer and on iOS the reflections are fine. This leads me to believe that this may be an issue with the Model Viewer or the Scene Viewer on Android? Does anyone else have this kind of issue?

Screenshots for reference:

Correct 3d view on iOS:

[image: Correct 3d view on iOS]

Correct AR view on iOS:

[image: Correct AR view on iOS]

Correct 3d view on Android:

[image: Correct 3d view on Android]

Incorrect AR view on Android (satin finish):

[image: Incorrect AR view on Android]

Comment: Hi can you help me with this error if you have solved it @Luca

Comment: @Abhishek Sadly I was not able to solve it myself, I'm sorry.